# Ability to leave comments broken

Tags: comments

At some point, my readers were able to add comments on both the main (front) page of my site and from the post pages as well.

Without any obvious change to the configuration of my site, the comment form has disappeared from my article page and, when I click the link from the front page to "add a comment," I'm brought to the article page with no comment form.

You can see the behavior at http://www.full-stack.net.

Comment: What Theme are you using? If the code is custom, then we will need to see the *actual code* in order to answer this question.

Comment: Just the out-of-the-box Twenty-ten theme with a custom header image and a single text widget added for AdSense.

Comment: What Plugins do you have *active*? Twenty Ten OOTB comments work just fine, so something else is causing this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify comments are enabled by default: Dashboard -> Settings -> Discussion -> Default article settings.

Verify comments are enabled for all posts/pages: Dashboard -> Posts -> Check all posts. -> Bulk actions (Edit) -> enable comments.

Same thing for pages.

Verify your template files. Do you still have a comments.php file?

Comment: Bulk action (edit) -> enable comments was the way to go. I'll vote up your answer as soon as I get enough rep.